# Can we scrap linkedin using python and without using selinium

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

can we scrap linkedin- job role ,company name, location, and respective job link without using Selenium in python

I've already tried using Selenium, but it gave me a lot of issues. I tried using Beautiful Soup instead, and it worked great[https://imgur.com/a/4Ge5fKe] output ss which i converted to csv
Now, all I'm waiting for a response that looks like my code and  a different code . I need to analyze those codes to gain some knowledge. You can assist me  happy coding!!!!!!!